# Most efficient way to groupby => aggregate for large dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, optimization

I have a pandas dataframe with roughly 150,000,000 rows in the following format:

```
df.head()

Out[1]:
     ID    TERM    X
0    1     A       0
1    1     A       4
2    1     A       6
3    1     B       0
4    1     B       10
5    2     A       1
6    2     B       1
7    2     F       1
```

I want to aggregate it by ID & TERM, and count the number of rows.  Currently I do the following:

```
df.groupby(['ID','TERM']).count()

Out[2]:
     ID    TERM    X
0    1     A       3
1    1     B       2
2    2     A       1
3    2     B       1
4    2     F       1
```

But this takes roughly two minutes.  The same operation using R data.tables takes less than 22 seconds.  Is there a more efficient way to do this in python?

For comparison, R data.table:

```
system.time({ df[,.(.N), .(ID, TERM)] })
#user: 30.32 system: 2.45 elapsed: 22.88
```

Comment: That seems like the right approach.  I did some timings on 10,000 rows with size instead of count as @jezrael suggests but that didn't seem any better.  I'd have thought python would be as fast or faster than R here so I'm kinda surprised.  But often you can increase the speed of a pandas method by writing a custom numpy or numba function, so that might be the next thing to try.

Comment: Oh, a reason R might be faster here is if pandas is hitting memory limits as pandas is not always real memory efficient (and that might be why numpy might speed things up a bit).  In that case options are to either do the calculation in chunks, find a computer with more memory, or look into blaze, dask, etc. as @jezrael mentions

Comment: Would `TERM` always hold single character strings?

Comment: @Divakar not necessarily.  In this case it's a string, but in other use cases it's an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A NumPy solution would be like so -

```
def groupby_count(df):
    unq, t = np.unique(df.TERM, return_inverse=1)
    ids = df.ID.values
    sidx = np.lexsort([t,ids])

    ts = t[sidx]
    idss = ids[sidx]

    m0 = (idss[1:] != idss[:-1]) | (ts[1:] != ts[:-1])
    m = np.concatenate(([True], m0, [True]))
    ids_out = idss[m[:-1]]
    t_out = unq[ts[m[:-1]]]
    x_out = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(m)+1)

    out_ar = np.column_stack((ids_out, t_out, x_out))
    return pd.DataFrame(out_ar, columns = [['ID','TERM','X']])
```

A bit simpler version -

```
def groupby_count_v2(df):    
    a = df.values
    sidx = np.lexsort(a[:,:2].T)
    b = a[sidx,:2]
    m = np.concatenate(([True],(b[1:] != b[:-1]).any(1),[True]))
    out_ar = np.column_stack((b[m[:-1],:2], np.diff(np.flatnonzero(m)+1)))
    return pd.DataFrame(out_ar, columns = [['ID','TERM','X']])
```

Sample run -

```
In [332]: df
Out[332]: 
   ID TERM   X
0   1    A   0
1   1    A   4
2   1    A   6
3   1    B   0
4   1    B  10
5   2    A   1
6   2    B   1
7   2    F   1

In [333]: groupby_count(df)
Out[333]: 
  ID TERM  X
0  1    A  3
1  1    B  2
2  2    A  1
3  2    B  1
4  2    F  1
```

Let's randomly shuffle the rows and verify that it works with our solution -

```
In [339]: df1 = df.iloc[np.random.permutation(len(df))]

In [340]: df1
Out[340]: 
   ID TERM   X
7   2    F   1
6   2    B   1
0   1    A   0
3   1    B   0
5   2    A   1
2   1    A   6
1   1    A   4
4   1    B  10

In [341]: groupby_count(df1)
Out[341]: 
  ID TERM  X
0  1    A  3
1  1    B  2
2  2    A  1
3  2    B  1
4  2    F  1
```

Comment: This was fast and avoided running out of memory, thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this solution to n groupby dimensions? eg:
`def grouby_count_v3(df, cols_to_groupby=[...]):`